# Rules of arg, kwarg unpacking

Tags: python, python-3.x

What are all the places that (kw)arg unpacking can be used?

For example:

```
>>> a={1:2}
>>> b={3:4}

# ok
>>> {**a,**b}
{1: 2, 3: 4}

# ok
>>> [*a]
>>> [1]

# error
>>> (*a)
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

What are all the 'rules' that starred-expressions abide by?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpacking works in a tuple too. However, a single-item tuple (also known as a singleton) has to include a comma at the end of the expression enclosed in the parentheses, or else the parentheses would be treated as simple grouping, so do instead:

```
(*a,)
```